# Getting response in network but console return error with cross origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I'm using google map api for web...
Also I'm calling search nearby api directly from jquery to search places,
this is error in console
[image: this is my error in console]
this is response in network
[image: this is my response in network]

I've already added to use api from all referrer in google api console.

```
     var param = {
        key: "My_Key",
        location: pos.lat+','+pos.lng,
        radius: 3000,
        type: "church"
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" + jQuery.param(param),
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the [Places API web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/) from javascript on the client, use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

[example in documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search)

[proof of concept fiddle (using the posted request parameters)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0t0zmg5z/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '3000',
    type: ['church']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: thanks....i  found that lst night when i  was reading docs by google, i didn't used the libraries at that time

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dataType : 'jsonp'` in your `$.ajax` call as,

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" + jQuery.param(param),
        method: "GET",
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : got this  error

Comment: @RaviVasoya there is a missing comma after `dataType : 'jsonp'`

Comment: @RaviVasoya Added comma and updated the code, Can you please try with updated code?

Comment: already done that also, $.ajax({
            url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" + jQuery.param(param),
            method: "GET",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false,
            success: function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });       now i'm not getting api call in network